# Error parsing nested JSON using Moshi

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, moshi

**Error received**

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $

**JSON being parsed**

*shortened to make it easier to read*

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "review_on_me": [
            {
                "request_id": "51",
                "review_from": "9",
                "reviewer": {
                    "id": 9,
                    "first_name": "abc",
                    "device_meta": {
                        "device_type": "iphone",
                        "device_id": "abc"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "latitude": "43.881731",
                        "longitude": "-79.444322"
                    }
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class ResponseGetReviews
 {
    @Json(name = "success")
    private Boolean success;
    @Json(name = "error")
    private String error;
    @Json(name = "data")
    private ReviewDataModel data;
}
```

**JSON Adapter being used**

Several of these for all subsequent data objects. This one is to show what they are like

```
public class ResponseGetReviewsAdapter extends JsonAdapter<ResponseGetReviews>
{
    @Override
    public ResponseGetReviews fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<ResponseGetReviews> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(ResponseGetReviews.class);

        return jsonAdapter.fromJson(reader.nextString());
    }

    @Override
    public void toJson(JsonWriter writer, ResponseGetReviews value) throws IOException
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<ResponseGetReviews> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(ResponseGetReviews.class);

        writer.value(jsonAdapter.toJson(value));
    }
}
```

**Function call**

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
                .add(ResponseGetReviews.class, new ResponseGetReviewsAdapter())
                .add(ReviewDataModel.class, new ReviewDataModelAdapter())
                .add(ReviewDetailModel.class, new ReviewDetailModelAdapter())
                .add(UserModel.class, new UserModelAdapter())
                .add(LocationModel.class, new LocationModelAdapter())
                .add(DeviceMetaModel.class, new DeviceMetaModelAdapter())
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RestAPI.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .build();
        RestAPI restApi = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
        Call<ResponseGetReviews> getReviewsCall = restApi.getClientReviews(auth, clientId);
```

Comment: no need to make new Moshi instances within the adapters. that's what the JsonAdapter.Factory is for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `return jsonAdapter.fromJson(reader.nextString());`. In this way you're saying that you want to read a `String` out of your JSON, but since you're at the beginning of the object (that's what the `$` in the error message means), you don't have a string, but rather an object.